# How to do actions before the gwt app restarts/closes?

Tags: java, database, gwt, save, finalize

I'm building a standart GWT web app and I am also using a MySql database.
Everytime I recompile my app my database is dropped and starts over.
I know I can stop it from dropping the table but I also want to save my database before everytime I recompile it.
My questions are:
1. where do I put that method and how do I "use it"?
2. What is the best option in your opinions to save that database?

thanks for the help

Comment: Where do you put the method to drop the database?

Comment: no... The drop database is done with mysql... i'm asking when I run a gwt on localhost... see that everything works and than shutsdown the app to continue coding in it. So i wanna do some actions before the app closes

how to do that...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform some action before the app closes, just add an event handler like this

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler(){
                    @Override
                    public void onWindowClosing(Window.ClosingEvent event) {    
                        /*do some actions before app closes*/
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ServletContextListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). Then you can listen to `contextInitialized` and `contextDestroyed` events that are (in short) web-app-start and web-app-stop:

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // app has started
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // app has stopped
    }
}
```

You also need to put this in your `web.xml` (replace with actual package name which must be on **server side**):

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.adam.test.server.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```